# Start and Schedule Cisco WebEx Meetings within Salesforce with MS Outlook Integration

Tags: integration, salesforce-for-outlook, outlook, connect-for-outlook

I am currently looking for a product that is something close to the defunct **Web Meeting Mashup** app created by DreamFactory (https://www.dreamfactory.com/webex/about_concepts.html). As a little info of what I'm looking for, this app is a business mashup of the ff.:

- WebEx
- Salesforce.com
- Microsoft Outlook

It allows users to schedule, start, join, list, invite and manage WebEx meetings from within the context of familiar Salesforce.com screens.

The nearest product I could find is Esna's **iLink for WebEx** (http://www.esna.com/products/ilink/webex/index.htm). The only problem is, it's using google instead of MS.

Any insights and previous encounters regarding this topic are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: you might try posting this at success.salesforce.com where there are more end-user-type expert members

Answer (score 1):

webex.esna.com supports google but is not required it can authenticate directly to Salesforce.com only and allows you to launch , schedule and log webex events right from salesforce.com.